# Lie algebra of the semiorthogonal group $O(p,q)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

How do I prove this: If $\mathcal{O}(p,q)$ is a Lie algebra of the semiorthogonal group $O(p,q)$ then $\mathcal O(p,q)$  consist of all matrices of the form:

$$X=
  \left( \begin{matrix}
        a & x^t\\
        x & b \\
   \end{matrix}
\right),$$

where $a\in \mathcal O(p)$ and $b\in \mathcal O(q)$, and $x$ is an arbitrary real matrix $q \times p$.

Answer (score 3):

Well you just do the same thing we do every night, Pinky, try to take over the world! Hm, well, I mean, compute differentials of curves.

Suppose that $\gamma$ is a smooth curve in $O(p,q)$ such that $\gamma(0)=I$, the identity matrix. If $x$ and $y$ are two vectors and $\def\i#1{\langle#1\rangle}$ is the usual quadratic form of signature $(p,q)$ on $\mathbb R^{p+q}$ then $\i{\gamma(t)x,\gamma(t)y}$ does not depend on $t$, so differentiating with respect to $t$ we see that $$0=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\i{\gamma(t)x,\gamma(t)y}=\i{\gamma'(t)x,\gamma(t)y}+\i{\gamma(t)x,\gamma(t)'y}$$ and evaluating at $t=0$, $$0=\i{\gamma'(0)x,y}+\i{x,\gamma(0)'y}.$$ If $x=e_i$ and $y=e_j$ are vectors in the standard basis, then this tells us that $$a_{i,j}\epsilon_j+a_{j,i}\epsilon_i=0.$$ Here $a_{i,j}$ is the $(i,j)$th entry in the matrix $\gamma'(0)$ and $\epsilon_i$ is $1$ if $1\leq i\leq p$, and $-1$ if $p+1\leq i\leq p+q$.
These equations imply that the matrix $\gamma'(0)$ is of the form you want.

This means that the tangent vector space at $I$ is contained in the vector space you wrote in your question. Now compare dimensions.

---

If you do not know already the dimension of the group, well, you need more work. Let now $A$ be a matrix in the space you wrote and consider the curve $\gamma:t\mapsto e^{At}$. More or less the same reasoning as above show that the function $t\mapsto\i{\gamma(t)x,\gamma(t)y}$ is constant, so that the curve is contained in your group. As its tangent vector at zero is the matrix $A$, this proves the other containment.

Comment: I want to add, as it's bugging me for a while now.
Proof of the other inclusion without using dimension:
In the answer above we see that $\mathfrak{o}(p,q)\subseteq I_{p,q} \mathfrak{so}(n)$.
For the other direction take $A \in \mathfrak{so}(n)$, i.e. symmetric and consider 
$\exp(I_{p,q}) I_{p,q}\exp(I_{p,q})^t$.
Open up the exponent as a series, divide both series to even and odd while noticing that $I_{p,q}^2=I$ and get
$\cos(A)I_{p,q}\cos(A)+\sin(A)I_{p,q}\sin(A)$.
But as both $A,I_{p,q}$ are symmetric they commute so we get 
$(\cos^2(A)+\sin^2(A))I_{p,q}=I_{p,q}$ and we're done.